# Python module that can convert .gpx to .kml

Tags: gps, kml, python-module, gpx

I am looking for a python module that would allow me to convert GPS .gpx files (from various devices) into .kml. Similary to what [LoadMyTrack](http://www.cluetrust.com/LoadMyTracks.html) does.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Gpsbabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/download.html) it's not a python module but it can be used standalone without an installer.  You can call it through popen or similar calls with python.